# Eclipse Logcat: only shows “Device disconnected”

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, ddms

When I run `GeoQuiz`, the only output I got from Logcat is "Device Disconnected"
I tried several ways to fix this but they didn’t work.

Click the device, aka the emulator, but still nothing;
Reset ADB, didn’t work either.
This’s really frustrating. So, please, anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Try following in command-line :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I accidentally fix it but don't know how. Maybe it is about the ads.exe version, which I replace it with an old one.

Comment: Try to use **Android Studio** it has some great features.